# Separate zsh histories after restart (iTerm2)

Tags: iterm, zsh

I am running iTerm2 (v 3.2.9) and zsh (v 5.7.1). I normally have 3-4 iTerm tabs opened at the same time and each tab has its own history thanks to the following settings in my `.zshrc` file

```
SAVEHIST=10000 # Number of entries
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history

unsetopt inc_append_history
unsetopt share_history
setopt appendhistory
```

However, when I close and re-open iTerm2 all tabs share the same history (I suppose they are reading from the very same `HISTFILE`): for example, if I have two tabs (say A and B), where the last command from A is `foo` and the last command from B is `bar`, when I close and re-open iTerm2 both tabs see either `bar` or `foo` (depending on the latest command which has been run, regardless of A or B) as the last entered command (arrow up key).

My question is: it is possible to keep separate histories even after re-launching iTerm2?

Comment: This isn't a real answer because I haven't done all the legwork, but it seems possible that you could have those different terminals be launched from different profiles, each with a different zsh command line that specified a different .zshrc file or dotfiles directory. That way those tabs would always come back with the options you prefer. I've searched a bit for this and I'm pretty convinced it could work. I can say for certain that I get a lot of mileage out of multiple iTerm2 profiles for building different local term sessions.

Comment: Not sure, whether it works, but this is how I would try it: Startup each zsh with an environment variable denoting the "kind" of the session; say: `SESSION=foo zsh -i .....`. In your .zshrc you do then a `HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history.$SESSION`. This should reuse this particular history.